# Counting number of spanning trees of graph

Tags: graph-theory, trees

[image]

In the graph above, I should count the number of possible spanning trees. Firstly, I looked at the cycles on the rightmost side and I have $2 \times 3$ for that half; but there are also cycles on the leftmost side of the graph and I concluded that are $2 \times 8$ spanning trees for that half. So there would be $96$ spanning trees but that seems to be an overcount. Any suggestions?

Comment: I counted only $5$ spanning trees in the right part and $12$ in the left part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I drew the two parts of the graph as below. I removed self-loops (since they cannot be in the spanning tree) and bridges (since they must be in the spanning tree).[image: Labelling]

We can count the spanning trees in the following manner.
The following $12$ set of edges form the spanning tree on the left half.
$$\{{a,b,c\}},\{{a,b,d\}},\{{a,b,e\}},\{{a,b,f\}},\{{a,c,d\}},\{{a,c,e\}},\{{a,c,f\}},\{{b,c,d\}},\{{b,d,e\}},\{{b,d,f\}},\{{c,d,e\}},\{{c,d,f\}}.$$

For the right half, the following $5$ sets:

$$ \{{a,b\}},\{{a,c\}},\{{a,d\}},\{{b,c\}},\{{b,d\}}.$$

Since we can pick only one from each side for a valid spanning tree, we have $12*5=60$ spanning trees.